# Selecting a Database

Tags: mysql, sql, cpanel

I am using PHPMyAdmin that is a part of cPanel for a website of mine. My question is this: How can I specify a database such that I can create tables etc for the specified database.

My database name is canningi_db_person_cdtest

Currently, I am using the following statement in the Query textbox:

```
use canningi_db_person_cdtest
```

I get the following information:

```
Your SQL Query has been executed successfully
```

The webpage then refreshes, and if I try and create a table, I am getting the following error:

```
No database selected
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a semicolon at the end of the database name. For example:

```
USE database;
SELECT * FROM table
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/use.html

Answer (score 0):

Trying to open this URL in your Web Browser :

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/
```

and then you can see all of database lists.

or if you using SQL command, try this :

```
use YOURDATABASENAME;
```